# Error when trying to parse XML in R

Tags: r, xml, data-science

I keep getting error while trying to parse xml file in R.

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
library(XML)
fileUrl <- "http://www.w3schools.com/xml/simple.xml"
doc <- xmlTreeParse(fileUrl, useInternal=TRUE)
```

I get these error below:
"

> ```
> Opening and ending tag mismatch: meta line 4 and head
> StartTag: invalid element name
> Opening and ending tag mismatch: br line 73 and p
> Opening and ending tag mismatch: br line 94 and body
> Opening and ending tag mismatch: br line 93 and html
> Premature end of data in tag br line 92
> Premature end of data in tag br line 78
> Premature end of data in tag br line 77
> ...
> ...
> 16: Premature end of data in tag br line 64
> 17: Premature end of data in tag body line 63
> 18: Premature end of data in tag meta line 3
> 19: Premature end of data in tag head line 2
> 20: Premature end of data in tag html line 2
> ```

"

**I am using R version 3.3.2 on Windows 7. XML lib version is 3.98.1.5.**

Would be glad if anybody could help since this supposed to be a simple parsing but I get stuck in here.

Comment: Have you tried `xmlParse(fileUrl, useInternalNodes = FALSE)`  `xmlParse()` and `xmlTreeParse()` are identical except that the default value of useInternalNodes has different values.

Comment: I have tried those and it still outputs same result.

Answer (score 1):

With package `XML` it works for me, being the output (with `dplyr` to have the output in `data.frame`):

```
library(XML)
library(dplyr)

fileUrl <- "http://www.w3schools.com/xml/simple.xml"
doc <- xmlTreeParse(fileUrl, useInternal=TRUE) %>%
  xmlToDataFrame()
doc

name price                                                                         description calories
1             Belgian Waffles $5.95                   Two of our famous Belgian Waffles with plenty of real maple syrup      650
2  Strawberry Belgian Waffles $7.95                   Light Belgian waffles covered with strawberries and whipped cream      900
3 Berry-Berry Belgian Waffles $8.95 Light Belgian waffles covered with an assortment of fresh berries and whipped cream      900
4                French Toast $4.50                                 Thick slices made from our homemade sourdough bread      600
5         Homestyle Breakfast $6.95                 Two eggs, bacon or sausage, toast, and our ever-popular hash browns      950
```

Another option is to try with library `xml2`:

```
library(xml2)
library(dplyr)

fileUrl <- "http://www.w3schools.com/xml/simple.xml"

# As a list
doc <-read_xml(fileUrl) %>% 
  as_list()
```

Comment: It still fails me somehow. But I found a way to make it work. I downloaded the simple.xml to my local directory and parse the xml file from local directory. It works fine. I am not quite sure why I cannot parse it from the website. 

Is it possible that the xml file in the w3schools website is contained inside a html? That is why it cannot be parsed.

Comment: @ggsdc if I am sucess with the second way and get the list. How could I convert that list to usable df format? any suggestion?